# SP TimeOut in .NET code, not in Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, timeout

If I run the following in Management Studio (SQL Server 2008) :

```
exec [USP_CNT_BookingDetail_ExtractAccountingPlanData] '4AFD6633-CB90-4165-913D-EE3EA74708DA', '7EF7CCB2-E09F-4408-AE2D-F857C063F2C1'
```

I get the result back in less than a second

I however I run it in VB.Net like this :

```
Using aConnection = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(*** Some Connection String ***)
  aConnection.Open()
  Dim aCmd = aConnection.CreateCommand()
  aCmd.CommandText = "exec [USP_CNT_BookingDetail_ExtractAccountingPlanData] '4AFD6633-CB90-4165-913D-EE3EA74708DA', '7EF7CCB2-E09F-4408-AE2D-F857C063F2C1'"
  aCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
  aConnection.Close()
End Using
```

it times out (I know that ExecuteNonQuery does not return data, but I tried to keep the code as small as possible).

I've used the same DB, UserID and password in code as in the Management Studio en the Isolation Level is Read Comitted.

Anybody has any idea ?

Comment: [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS? Understanding Performance Mysteries](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)

Comment: Have you already upped the CommandTimeout to see if the proc will return eventually?  e.g. you know for sure the the proc is running, but is just slow via VB.

Comment: Have you retrieved and compared execution plans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using SET ARITHABORT ON; fixed the problem.

Comment: You should probably read this article. http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html

Answer (score 1):

Try turning on SQL Profiler and comparing what is being processed during the two calls.

Also, in Management Studio run these command prior to testing your procedure :

```
CHECKPOINT
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
```

These commands will make sure that your SSMS testing is getting a fresh start when it runs that procedure. It is likely that, rather than your VB.NET giving an erroneously slow result, your SSMS testing is giving a false quick one due to prior executions.

[CHECKPOINT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188748.aspx)
[DROPCLEANBUFFERS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188748.aspx)
[SO post on subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/382122/can-someone-explain-dbcc-dropcleanbuffers)

Comment: I would have thought the issue will be much more likely to be parameter sniffing.

Comment: Even when he's passing the same parameter values in both places? I have seen the problem myself when there are no parameters.

Comment: @CodeByMoonlight - Yes. SSMS has a different default for `ARITH_ABORT` than `.NET` code does (this makes **no functional effect whatsoever** as when SET `ANSI_WARNINGS` is on SQL Server acts as though `ARITH_ABORT` is on anyway). It's only effect is that of a plan cache key so typically someone will notice that the application is running slowly copy and paste the query with the same parameters into SSMS and discover that it runs fast (because the query has just been compiled with those parameter values). They may then turn off `ARITH_ABORT` in SSMS and discover it runs slowly so it appears...

Comment: ... that they have found the culprit. Toggling this option off means that they just end up getting the same cached plan that their application uses however hence the difference in performance.

Comment: Interesting :) I can see that in the profiler, as well as 'set numeric_roundabort off' which doesn't seem to be an option in the SSMS GUI.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's used as a plan cache key or not. You can try `SELECT * FROM   sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cp CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(plan_handle) t CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(plan_handle) qp CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_plan_attributes(plan_handle) AS epa WHERE  t.text LIKE '%Some text in your query%' AND epa.attribute = 'set_options'` to see both plans and look at the `use_count` field to see whether toggling `ARITH_ABORT` means you end up re-using the same plan in SSMS as your application is using.

Answer (score -1):

Can change your CommandText to a simple query "UPDATE TableABC SET Field1 = Field1 WHERE ID = XYZ" to see if it's the proc or the connection string itself.  My guess is the proc is fine and there is probably something off in the conn.