# Sql query and matching strings/numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, string-matching

I am working with several tables. An Employee table (tblEmployee), a Managers table (tblManager), and a manager log table (tblLog). In the log table there is about 10 columns. The first column is the manager ID. There is another column that has the first name of an employee to be transferred, and to which dept that employee should go to. Below is a snapshot of that column:

```
Bob- Dept: 7 Meg- Dept: 5 
Bob- Dept: 7 Meg- Dept: 5  
Bob- Dept: 7 Meg- Dept: 5 
Preston- Dept: 1 
Martin- Dept: MANG Sue- Dept: MANG Sarah - DEPT: 8 
Martin- Dept: MANG Sue- Dept: MANG Sarah - DEPT: 8
Martin- Dept: MANG Sue- Dept: MANG Sarah - DEPT: 8 
Isabel- Dept: 6 Mike- Dept: 5 
Isabel- Dept: 6 Mike- Dept: 5  
Dan- Dept: MANG
Dan- Dept: MANG
```

As you can see, there are duplicate rows. The manager who is recommending Bob and Meg be transferred has 3 rows for his ID. That is because he has 3 employees in the table, a row for each employee. I am working on extracting just the employees that are being transferred to management (MANG) or another dept(#1-8). I have a query written that gets all of the information I need, but it gets every employee in the log table, it currently does not filter out the extra ones. So say I am returning 150 rows, there are actually only 100 employee tranfers and 50 other employees who are in the log table for a different reason.

I was trying to come up with a query that takes the first name of the employee and checks if it is in the column, then takes the employees future dept number (from tblEmployee) and checks that it matches the number in the log column. I have looked at `PARTINDEX` and REGEXs but I am not skilled enough to come up with a solution that can achieve the desired result

Comment: Please show the layout of the table.  It is hard to understand what is a column name and what is a column value with your layout.

Comment: If you unable to come up with the query, then at the very least show your sample data for every table and the desired result based on this data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little vague in terms of the details of the data model.  Having tried to understand your question, my advice would be to consider rewriting you data model as I personally think it leaves a bit to be desired when you want to calculate this type of query.

Rant aside, I've tried to guess your data model based what you've described in your question, and assume it is something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tblLog(
    ManagerID int,
    log varchar(max)
 )

INSERT INTO tbllog values
(1, 'Bob- Dept: 7 Meg- Dept: 5'),
(1, 'Bob- Dept: 7 Meg- Dept: 5'),
(1, 'Bob- Dept: 7 Meg- Dept: 5'), 
(2, 'Preston- Dept: 1'), 
(3, 'Martin- Dept: MANG Sue- Dept: MANG Sarah - DEPT: 8'),
(3, 'Martin- Dept: MANG Sue- Dept: MANG Sarah - DEPT: 8'),
(3, 'Martin- Dept: MANG Sue- Dept: MANG Sarah - DEPT: 8'), 
(4, 'Isabel- Dept: 6 Mike- Dept: 5'), 
(4, 'Isabel- Dept: 6 Mike- Dept: 5'),  
(5, 'Dan- Dept: MANG'),
(5, 'Dan- Dept: MANG') 


CREATE TABLE tblEmployee(
    FirstName varchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO tblEmployee values
('Bob'), ('Meg'), ('Preston'), ('Martin'), ('Sue'), ('Sarah'), ('Isabel'), ('Mike'), ('Dan')
```

If it is like this, then finding the info you want is relatively trivial (although because of the way you've got the data stored, computationally inefficient)

```
DECLARE @vcDepartment VARCHAR(50) = 'MANG'


SELECT DISTINCT
    tblLog.ManagerID,
    tblEmployee.FirstName
FROM
    tblLog,
    tblEmployee
WHERE
    tblLog.Log like '%' + tblEmployee.FirstName + '- DEPT: ' + @vcDepartment + '%'
OR  tblLog.Log like '%' + tblEmployee.FirstName + ' - DEPT: ' + @vcDepartment + '%'
```

I've put the answer in an sql fiddle so you can verify the solution and play with it if you desire: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d22df/1/0

Hope that points you in the right direction.

Comment: I will let you know if this worked out when I implement it, but it certainly looks like it will do the trick

Comment: worked very well!, I would like to add the query was faster like this:    `CHARINDEX(tblEmployee.FirstName+ ' - DEPT: ' + @vcDepartment, Log) > 0`. The `LIKE` took 4 secs and the `CHARINDEX` less than a second. And it seems that adding a full text index and using contains would be even faster

Comment: @user3685738 It's interesting that. Out of interest, if you run the command 'set statistics io on', what are the stats reported for each way?  If you ran one way after having run the other, then the second may well have run faster due to the way sql server caches things.  If you want to see how your query really behaves, then do [a checkpoint and issue a dbcc dropcleanbuffers command.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/382151/1208914)